# update using nested queries in oracle sql-developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 records in nltl table which all have different locked_dt => date on which it was locked. Now I want to update the is_locked flag in it for the record which is at the last place(oldest date) i.e at 3rd rank. The inner sub-query is working fine but the sub-query along with the update statement is giving issues (SQL command not properly ended)

nltl table: {
l_id, c_id, e_id, t_id, ee_id, locked_dt, is_locked
}

```
update nltl set is_locked = 0
from (
        select t_id, l_id, e_id, ee_id, c_id, is_locked from (
        select ppl.*, DENSE_RANK() over (order by ppl.locked_dt desc) my_rnk
        from nltl ppl
        where ppl.l_d = 17 and ppl.t_id = 55 and ppl.c_id = 3 and ppl.e_id = 1509919001 and ppl.ee_id = 15099190
        ) t where my_rnk = 3
    )
    
where t_id = t.t_id, l_id = t.l_id, e_id = t.e_id, ee_id = t.ee_id, c_id = t.c_id;
```

Comment: Give a name after from like this: ``update nltl set is_locked=0 from (...)  x`` and no need to select ``is_locked`` in sub query

Comment: Did you check the syntax of [`UPDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5) statement? There's no place for `FROM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) statement for this purpose since Oracle does not support `UPDATE` statement with table as a source. But as long as your new value does not depend on any calculated value, this can be done with simple `IN` predicate:

```
update nltl t
set is_locked = 0
where (l_id, c_id, e_id, t_id, ee_id, locked_dt) in (
  select ppl.l_id, ppl.c_id, ppl.e_id, ppl.t_id, ppl.ee_id, ppl.locked_dt
  from (
    select
      ppl.*,
      dense_rank() over (order by ppl.locked_dt desc) my_rnk
    from nltl ppl
    where
      ppl.l_d = 17
      and ppl.t_id = 55
      and ppl.c_id = 3
      and ppl.e_id = 1509919001
      and ppl.ee_id = 15099190
  )
  where my_rnk = 3
)
```

Or use physical row addres to do it without indexes or full table scan:

```
update nltl t
set is_locked = 0
where rowid in (
  select rid
  from (
    select
      ppl.rowid as rid,
      dense_rank() over (order by ppl.locked_dt desc) my_rnk
    from nltl ppl
    where
      ppl.l_d = 17
      and ppl.t_id = 55
      and ppl.c_id = 3
      and ppl.e_id = 1509919001
      and ppl.ee_id = 15099190
  )
  where my_rnk = 3
)
```

Comment: Can I connect to you somehow I had another doubt regarding this @astentx

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge as follows:

```
Merge into nltl t
Using (select t_id, l_id, e_id, ee_id, c_id from (
        select ppl.*, DENSE_RANK() over (order by ppl.locked_dt desc) my_rnk
        from nltl ppl
        where ppl.l_d = 17 and ppl.t_id = 55 and ppl.c_id = 3 and ppl.e_id = 1509919001 and ppl.ee_id = 15099190
        ) t where my_rnk = 3) s
On (s.t_id = t.t_id 
   And s.l_id = t.l_id
   And s.e_id = t.e_id
   And s.ee_id = t.ee_id
   And s.c_id = t.c_id)
When matched then 
  Update set t.is_locked=0
```